# Obtener datos de un formulario y crear una url a la cual me redireccione con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un formulario y quisiera que cuando aprieten un botón me redireccione a una página con los valores en la url, algo como esto:

> "www.google.com?nom=luis&em=lcamposn@outlook.com".

Este es mi código:

```
<button id="send" onclick="prueba()">Enviar</button>
<script>

function prueba() {
    var id = getParameterByName('id');
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var ocupacion = document.getElementById("ocupacion").value;
    var dni = document.getElementById("dni").value;
    var edad = document.getElementById("edad").value;
    var estadoc = document.getElementById("estadoc").value;
    var distrito = document.getElementById("distrito").value;
    var nombrecon = document.getElementById("nombrecon").value;
    var emailcon = document.getElementById("emailcon").value;
    var ocupacioncon = document.getElementById("ocupacioncon").value;
    var url = "https://creator.zohopublic.com/sandravillar/boarding-pass/page-perma/confirmation/NGDQsTnjyyWXYab9CWjGhVF0pQpZy9fMAeVK1nXgqkpjzAawVEWEMryRZseaeRHY5PzNk5qFRd8Dsu7XJg2JKMCwHTedsmTr1rej" + "?id=" + id + "&em=" + email + "&ocu=" + ocupacion + "&dni=" + dni + "&edad=" + edad + "&est=" + estadoc + "&dis=" + dis + "&nomc=" + nombrecon + "&emc=" + emailcon + "&ocuc=" + ocupacioncon;
    window.location = "'"+url+"'";     
}
```

¿Es posible lo que intento hacer?

Comment: Por qué usar JavaScript? Para lo que quieres hacer sólo tienes que usar el método get en tu formulario y que el botón de envío sea un imput type submit. Pasar por JavaScript si no vas a hacer algún tipo de validación u otra cosa no aportaría nada al ese tipo de envío de datos.

Comment: Hola Carmen, lo qué pasa es que veo que se utiliza get para paginas locales y yo tengo que enviar esos datos a una página externa. El lenguaje que utiliza se llama deluge y el único modo que veo sería enviarle datos por la url. Saludos

Comment: puedes enviarlo a una página externa con get, solo tienes que usar una url absoluta en lugar de relativa

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, si funcionó. Ya había intentado en un hosting gratuito pero no había funcionado. Hoy probando de nuevo el action con la url si funcionó. No entiendo porque no funcionó en ese momento. ¡Muy agradecido...!

Answer (score 0):

Si queres eviar datos mediante la URL te aconsejo de utilizar HTML en vez de Javascript :

```
<form method="GET" action="(tu url de destinacion">
    <input type="text" id="id">
    <input type="email" id="em" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <!-- mas datos que quieras pasar-->
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Si utilizas el metodo `GET` te permite enviar tu informacion codificada en la cabezera de la peticion HTTP, es decir, directamente en el URL.

> ¿Es posible lo que intento hacer?

la respuesta es si, pero te complicarias la vida y no tendria sentido ya que seria crear un duplicado del form html.

espero que te sea de ayuda.